# ASP NET Web Form Url Rewrite too slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, friendly-url, global-asax

I have a website (SITE_DOMAIN) that needs Url rewrite rules.
The site is in asp.net Web forms.

For Example SITE_DOMAIN/abbigliamento/donna/jeans Is SITE_DOMAIN/Products/Donna/0/42/1

I have a table called Rewrites with this fields

[image: IdRewrite Chiave Pagina Param1 Param2 Param3 Param4 Param5 Type 2173 abbigliamento/donna/jeans Products Donna 0 42 1 NULL Categorie]

In Global.asax I have

```
   public static List<Rewrite> rewrites = null;
   public static string oldChiave = "";

   public void GetRewrites() 
   {
      if (rewrites == null)
         rewrites = Rewrite.getRules(); //reads from table (about 5000 rows)
   }


protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      
      GetRewrites();
      String fullOriginalPath = Request.Url.ToString();
      int index = fullOriginalPath.IndexOf('/', fullOriginalPath.IndexOf(SITE_DOMAIN)) + 1;
      string chiave = fullOriginalPath.Substring(index).ToLower();

      if (oldChiave != chiave)
      {
         oldChiave = chiave;            

         Rewrite r = rewrites.Find(y => y.Chiave == chiave);

         if (r != null)
         {
            string url = "/" + r.Pagina;
            if (r.Param1 != null)
                url += "/" + r.Param1;
            if (r.Param2 != null)
                url += "/" + r.Param2;
            if (r.Param3 != null)
                url += "/" + r.Param3;
            if (r.Param4 != null)
                url += "/" + r.Param4;
            if (r.Param5 != null)
                url += "/" + r.Param5;
            Context.RewritePath(url);
         }

         //se non ho trovato la chiave all'interno delle chiavi potrebbe essere la composizione dei parametri in Param1,2,3,4,5 es /Products/Uomo/0/0/1, deve ritrasformarsi in Scarpe-Uomo
         string[] param = chiave.Split('/');
         if (param.Length == 5)
         {
            r = rewrites.Find(x => x.Pagina == param[0] &&
                    x.Param1 == param[1] &&
                    x.Param2 == param[2] &&
                    x.Param3 == param[3] &&
                    x.Param4 == param[4]);

            if (r != null)
                Response.Redirect("/" + r.Chiave);

         }
         if (param.Length == 6)
         {
            r = rewrites.Find(x => x.Pagina == param[0] &&
                    x.Param1 == param[1] &&
                    x.Param2 == param[2] &&
                    x.Param3 == param[3] &&
                    x.Param4 == param[4] &&
                    x.Param5 == param[5]);

            if (r != null)
                Response.Redirect("/" + r.Chiave);
         }
      }

   }
```

The website is too slow and the problem I'm sure it's here.

The Global.asax Application_BeginRequest method is fired 3 or more times when I click a link.

Is there any other method that I could use or any 3-part dll that I could use?

PS. for completeness in my global.asax I also have the method

```
    using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls;
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      RouteTable.Routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "home", "~/Default.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "carrello", "~/Carrello.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "contatti", "~/Contatti.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "checkout", "~/Checkout2.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "logout", "~/Logout.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "pagamenti", "~/Pagamenti.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "chi-siamo/scarpe-online-di-marca", "~/ChiSiamo.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "i-miei-ordini", "~/PageOrdini.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "pre-checkout", "~/PreCheckout.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "privacy-and-cookies", "~/PrivacyAndCookies.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "ricerca-prodotto/{Filtri}/{Pagina}", "~/ProductsSearch.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "il-mio-profilo", "~/Profilo.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "registrazione", "~/Registrazione.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "resi", "~/Resi.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "spedizioni", "~/Spedizioni.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "termini-e-condizioni", "~/TerminiECondizioni.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "grazie", "~/Thanks.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "product/{ProductId}", "~/Product.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "products/{Menu}/{Marca}/{Categoria}/{Pagina}", "~/Products.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "blog/{Pagina}", "~/Blog.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "lista-dei-desideri/{Pagina}", "~/Wishlist.aspx");
      RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "blogpost/{NewsId}", "~/BlogPost.aspx");

   }
```

This rewrites are fixed so, they don't need to be stored in the previous table.

Comment: If your are use Middleware for this, i think it would be give u better performance. https://www.infoworld.com/article/3445867/how-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware-in-aspnet-core.html

Comment: You haven't made any real attempt to profile how long each chunk of logic is actually taking to execute, so you will get varied solutions with no way of gauging which one is better for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are open to third party solutions ("Is there any other method that I could use or any 3-part dll that I could use?") you can consider the following.

1. Option 1: Since your website is built using Microsoft tech stack, I am assuming you would be deploying the solution on IIS webserver. If that is the case, you can you can use the Rewrite module extension on IIS to do all of your rewrites. Your rules would be saved in the web.config file.
2. Option 2:  Use third party software

Option 1 Steps

- Open IIS Manager. Select Your Web Site.
- Click URL Rewrite in the Feature View. If you don't see this option, URL rewrite extension might not have been installed. Get it from here [https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite] and install it.
- Click Add rules in the Actions pane (found on the right side)
- Select Blank Rule in the Add Rules dialog box
- Create your rules. Rule options are pretty self explanatory.

Since your rules are stored in a database, you might need to write code to read your rules from database (which you seems to have already done) and reformat the rules to confirm to IIS rule format. At the end of the day, rules are name-value pairs. Say you have a prod.aspx page that takes a product id and size parameters that displays product details and your current URL is "/products/prod.aspx?id=1234&size=3". The "original value" in the rule mapping will be "/product-details" and the "New Value" will be "/products/prod.aspx?id=1234&size=3" in IIS rule mapping dialog box. The original value specifies what URL path we want to rewrite from and the new value specifies what URL path we want to rewrite to.

You might need to use a custom Rewrite Provider with URL Rewrite Module to interface directly with your SQL tables to import rules. You can read more about how to do this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module

Option 2

- ISAPI Rewrite by Helicon Tech (http://www.isapirewrite.com/)
- Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter (https://github.com/DinoChiesa/IIRF)

I have not used any of the above software products myself and therefore, I couldn't tell you how well they work. Try them at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have suggested, there are different MiddleWare options available or Url-Rewrite modules that could be applied outside of your running application, but if you do not understand where your actual bottle necks are, how can you be sure that any changes in this area will be effective?

There are multiple compounding issues at play here.

1. #### The website is too slow

   What is your definition of *Too Slow* and what response times are you looking to achieve?

   - Whilst complex route logic looks like a prime candidate, even if it looks inefficient, worst case this should only add a couple of hundred milliseconds to each response.
   - Know that each page request, depending on the architecture and code within it will usually make multiple requests, sometimes 10s or 100s of individual requests for content, it might not be the routing that is the issue, but instead the servicing of the content at each of those, or perhaps just some of the requests that is the bottle neck.
   - Use the dev tools in your browser to identify which individual requests on a page life cycle are taking the longest to execute, the *slow* response might ***not*** be a significant factor.
2. #### Loading the list of routes

   Whilst what we assume to be a database call is loaded once into a static variable, the code pattern is ambiguous and instead of executing this "on request" it should be forced into a single call in the `Application_Start`. But do not overlook the importance of making sure this call is efficient, if this simple DB lookup takes too long to respond, then we can safely assume that all other queries against the database would also be slow, that is the **MOST LIKELY FACTOR** in your response times.

   - 5K records doesn't sound like too much, but in some frameworks and low cost architectures it might add a few seconds to cold start times, in which case you should consider a compilation or deployment step that reads the data from the database into a local file or use T4 templates or something similar to generate code from the rules.
   - You need to know how long `Rewrite.getRules()` takes to execute to make decisions around this point, simple code like this will help to capture the time spent getting the rules, if this is unacceptable then that is a clear place to optimise, I would expect 5k rows to still return under 1 second in a production environment:

     ```
     public static List<Rewrite> rewrites = null;
     public static TimeSpan _getRules_Duration = TimeSpan.Zero;

     public void GetRewrites() 
     {
        if (rewrites == null)
        {
            var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            try
            {
                rewrites = Rewrite.getRules(); //reads from table (about 5000 rows)
            }
            finally
            {
                sw.Stop();
                _getRules_Duration = sw.Elapsed;
            }
         }
     }
     ```

     > Post the value for `_getRules_Duration`, if it is more than 1 second then this indicates something is seriously wrong with your data access implementation. If a simple query like that takes too long, then your entire data driven web site is doomed from the start, see back to the above points, if a page makes multiple individual hits to the database then each of those queries may also be impacted by the poor performing DAL

     Even 1 second is being generous, I just profiled a much more complex EF query, returning over 10K rows, with 4 levels of Included relationship data, and the whole lot comes back in under 100ms, the whole page response is closer to 700ms, so even if I was to optimise the DB query, best case scenario is that the whole page load comes back closer to 600ms, so is it worth the effort for such a minimal improvement?

     > Poor DAL can be caused by poor code or poorly implemented ORM logic, however we often overlook the operating environment and resources that the deployed websites are running on. The latency between the web client, the web server, the DAL and then the database introduce crucial physical hardware bottlenecks to your code may need to respect if you can't improve the bandwidth or resources.

   Move the call to load the routes into `Application_Start` to make it obvious that this data is only loaded once in the application lifecycle, but it is needed for every request, so you want to know early if it is going to fail:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       GetRewrites();

       RouteTable.Routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
       ...
   }
   ```
3. #### Re-factor your logic so you can Test it

   Right now, OP and all other posts are focusing on logic used to match the routes, but similar to the load times, if the route logic only takes 200ms to evaluate then at best we can only reduce each individual response time by that amount. Lets refactor this logic into a format that we can both test and measure:

   ```
   private string oldChiave;
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       String fullOriginalPath = Request.Url.ToString();
       int index = fullOriginalPath.IndexOf('/', fullOriginalPath.IndexOf(SITE_DOMAIN)) + 1;
       string chiave = fullOriginalPath.Substring(index).ToLower();

       if (oldChiave != chiave)
       {
           oldChiave = chiave;
           if (TryGetRewritePath(chiave, out string rewriteUrl))
               Context.RewritePath(rewriteUrl);
           else if (TryGetRewritePath(chiave, out string redirectUrl))
               Context.Redirect(redirectUrl);
       }
   }

   public bool TryGetRewritePath(string chiave, out string url)
   {
       Rewrite r = rewrites.Find(y => y.Chiave == chiave);

       if (r != null)
       {
           string url = "/" + r.Pagina;
           if (r.Param1 != null)
               url += "/" + r.Param1;
           if (r.Param2 != null)
               url += "/" + r.Param2;
           if (r.Param3 != null)
               url += "/" + r.Param3;
           if (r.Param4 != null)
               url += "/" + r.Param4;
           if (r.Param5 != null)
               url += "/" + r.Param5;
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   public bool TryGetRedirectPath(string chiave, out string url)
   {
       //se non ho trovato la chiave all'interno delle chiavi potrebbe essere la composizione dei parametri in Param1,2,3,4,5 es /Products/Uomo/0/0/1, deve ritrasformarsi in Scarpe-Uomo
       string[] param = chiave.Split('/');
       if (param.Length == 5)
       {
           Rewrite r = rewrites.Find(x => x.Pagina == param[0] &&
                   x.Param1 == param[1] &&
                   x.Param2 == param[2] &&
                   x.Param3 == param[3] &&
                   x.Param4 == param[4]);

           if (r != null)
           {
               url = "/" + r.Chiave;
               return true;
           }
       }
       if (param.Length == 6)
       {
           Rewrite r = rewrites.Find(x => x.Pagina == param[0] &&
                   x.Param1 == param[1] &&
                   x.Param2 == param[2] &&
                   x.Param3 == param[3] &&
                   x.Param4 == param[4] &&
                   x.Param5 == param[5]);

           if (r != null)
           {
               url = "/" + r.Chiave;
               return true;
           }
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```

   Now, as with the `GetRewrites` example, we can again use the stop watch to record the duration of each request, here we will just trace out the info, you can adapt this to your needs, perhaps storing the max or average processing time

   > The overall point is that you need data to inform you if this is the source of your overall performance issues.

   ```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String fullOriginalPath = Request.Url.ToString();
        int index = fullOriginalPath.IndexOf('/', fullOriginalPath.IndexOf(SITE_DOMAIN)) + 1;
        string chiave = fullOriginalPath.Substring(index).ToLower();

        if (oldChiave != chiave)
        {
            oldChiave = chiave;

            var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            if (TryGetRewritePath(chiave, out string rewriteUrl))
            {
                sw.Stop();
                // log out the duration
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"URL Rewrite evaluated in: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms. '{chiave}' => '{rewriteUrl}'");
                Context.RewritePath(rewriteUrl);
            }
            else if (TryGetRewritePath(chiave, out string redirectUrl))
            {
                sw.Stop();
                // log out the duration (this includes the above dureation AS WELL)
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"URL Redirect evaluated in: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms. '{chiave}' => '{rewriteUrl}'");
                Context.Redirect(redirectUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                sw.Stop();
                // log out the duration (this includes the above dureation AS WELL)
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"NO REDIRECT evaluated in: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms. '{chiave}'");
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   OP please post the times that your code takes to complete these functions, from that you can decide if the route processing is significant factor or not.
4. #### Chiave Logic

   The other obvious issue in your code is that you have tried to prevent multiple evaluations of the route logic based on whether the `Chiave` has changed or not. If your site serves requests for multiple values of the path prefix, then I'm not sure this logic is entirely correct. If two different users operating under different business `Chiave` identities are using your site at the same time, then each user will cause the previous value of `oldChiave` to be overwritten and the same logic executed.

   As a minimal step, make sure that `oldChiave` is an *instance* member, and not a *static* member. But I'm not sure that is really helping your issue at all, what you probably want to implement is the following type of logic:

   ```
   On Request:
      - If the current URL has already been evaluated for redirect, use the previous result
      - Otherwise, check if we need to redirect, and if we do, cache the result for next time.
   ```

   As usual, there are a lot of different code patterns to go about this, however it is first important to *know* if this is going to improve your response times, and if so, by how much. That can only be determined by analysing the logic.

> Note here *static* is used, we don't know which application instance might be serving the request.

```
   static Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> rewriteCache = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>(); 
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       String fullOriginalPath = Request.Url.ToString();
       int index = fullOriginalPath.IndexOf('/', fullOriginalPath.IndexOf(SITE_DOMAIN)) + 1;
       string chiave = fullOriginalPath.Substring(index).ToLower();

       if (rewriteCache.TryGetValue(chiave, out Tuple<string, string> cacheItem))
       {
           if(cacheItem != null)
           {
               if(cacheItem.Item1 != null) Context.RewritePath(cacheItem.Item1);
               if(cacheItem.Item2 != null) Context.Redirect(cacheItem.Item2);
           }
       }
       else
       { 
           if (TryGetRewritePath(chiave, out string rewriteUrl))
           {
               rewriteCache.Add(chiave, new Tuple<string, string>(rewriteUrl, null));
               Context.RewritePath(rewriteUrl);
           }
           else if (TryGetRewritePath(chiave, out string redirectUrl))
           {
               rewriteCache.Add(chiave, new Tuple<string, string>(null, redirectUrl));
               Context.Redirect(redirectUrl);
           }
           else
           {
               // Cache the no redirect scenario
               rewriteCache.Add(chiave, null);
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Application_BeginRequest method is fired 3 or more times when I click
> a link

To minimize the calls -
the `Application_BeginRequest` is called on all request, not only on aspx files.

you can minimize only of on `aspx` and handlers files. Here is an example on how to do that:

```
    string sExtentionOfThisFile = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path);
    
if ( sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
     sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".ashx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
)
{
    // run here your Rewrites
}
```

> rewrites = Rewrite.getRules(); //reads from table (about 5000 rows)
>
> Rewrite r = rewrites.Find(y => y.Chiave == chiave);

This is the point where you make a search loop of 5000 times (maybe an average of 2500) on each call. Imaging if the most access page are at the end of the list, **then near 5000 compare strings on each call** - this is where you have the main issue.

To make it faster in your specific case, I suggest to use `Dictionary<>` - need a little bit more code and different way to search on it - but will make the different.

Also optimize that code with different way of search - this way using `Dictionary<>`

```
        r = rewrites.Find(x => x.Pagina == param[0] &&
                x.Param1 == param[1] &&
                x.Param2 == param[2] &&
                x.Param3 == param[3] &&
                x.Param4 == param[4]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have some problems: 1) trying to do the first if. If the caller page it's itself a rewrite, the extension is empty. 2) If I do a dictionary I'm ok until the Rewrite r = rewrites.Find(y => y.Chiave == chiave); that will be replaced with Rewrite r=rewrites[chiave] but I cannot do the last two find with Pagina and Param1,2 ecc in Where condition.

Comment: @Martina As it is maybe not - you need to think it a lot and optimize it - you can add extra parameters as cache results - I do not know what you have there -  but for sure you can optimize it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the verification of the extension as said by Aristos, and I would also perhaps search a "Find" implementation (using binary trees, or some other method) to make it faster.

I think that is the issue.

The query to the DB is not the issue since it runs one time only.

Another possible solution could be to setup the list in a redis server which is faster (although you need to run some tests to compare redis vs inmemory of 5000 items or more to make it futureproof)